# Having difficulty making sprites move in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a cursor move across an image, but I'm having problems making my cursor image (redcircle.png) move. When I run my program the circle jumps to my mouse pointer like it should, but then refuses to move until I reload it.
I'm very new to python, this stuff sends me through a loop, but none of the 55 pages and tutorials and crap I have open on it rn seem to give me a clear answer.

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

screen_width = 1250
screen_height = 800

size = screen_width, screen_height

speed = [60, 60]
black = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0,125)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

bg = pygame.image.load("redtest.png")
bgrect = bg.get_rect()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("redcircle.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

block = Block(black, 20, 15)
all_sprites_list.add(block)

screen.fill(black)
screen.blit(bg, bgrect)
all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

def main():
    while True:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        block.rect.x = pos[0]
        block.rect.y = pos[1]
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the background and to redraw the Group of Sprites in every frame. Furthermore you have to handle the events.

The main application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (draw the `Sprites` objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

e.g:

```py
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        # event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        # update objects
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        block.rect.x = pos[0]
        block.rect.y = pos[1]

        # draw background
        screen.blit(bg, bgrect)

        # d raw sprotes
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

        # update display
        pygame.display.update()
```